# boost::any_cast(const any&) uses const_cast<> -- Isn't this potentially UB?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

boost/any.hpp (version 1.55) defines (line 263)

```
template<typename ValueType>
inline const ValueType * any_cast(const any * operand) BOOST_NOEXCEPT
{
    return any_cast<ValueType>(const_cast<any *>(operand));
}
```

However, using `const_cast<>`, *may result in undefined behaviour* if the original object was *not declared `const`* as in

```
class foo
{
  boost::any value;
  template<typename T>
  foo(T const&x) noexcept : value(x) {}

  template<typename T>
  const T*ptr() const noexcept
  { return boost::any_cast(value); }
};
```

So, is boost kosher?

Comment: didn't you misquote there; UB if I remove const from originally non-const obj?

Comment: It could lead to UB *if* the function returned a pointer to the non-const value type, but it isn't. Constant in, constant out. The code inside the function? It's just casting and doesn't modify the object.

Comment: Hmm. I may have been misguided by older standards. So `const_cast<>(non_const_object)` is not (potentially) UB after all?

Comment: Older standards had no problem with that either AFAIK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is legal code, since `any_cast` returns const-pointer and `any_cast`, that receives pointer, does not change its argument.

UB by standard can be only in 1 situation if you use `const_cast`:

n3376 5.2.11/7

> [ Note: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through
>   the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a
>   const_cast that casts away a const-qualifier may produce undefined
>   behavior (7.1.6.1). — end note ]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are thinking of `[expr.const.cast]#7`:

> [Note: Depending on the type of the object, **a write operation** through the pointer, lvalue or pointer to data member resulting from a const_cast that casts away a const-qualifier 73 may produce undefined behavior (7.1.6.1). —end note ]

The section 7.1.6.1 is:

> Except that any class member declared mutable (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a const
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior

But there is no such write operation in this code. The rest of the `[expr.const.cast]` section says nothing to suggest that this code has a problem.